# A Mysterious Number Grid

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Okay, it's time to step away from the tag that I [may have accidentally revived](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess). I'm here with an interesting number grid:

[image]

I can't make anything out of it. What's worse, some of the numbers are missing, replaced with black squares. I'm told that one of the squares is wrong, and that the black squares are intentional, but I can't tell which square is wrong or what it should be replaced with, so that is your objective here.

There is a logical pattern to the grid. I promise.

Hints will be added as necessary.

Good luck.

Comment: HAHA nice comment on reviving the `chess` tag! You definitely inspired me to break out my board and try to create a few; but I'm getting back to work on my newest puzzle today as I was stuck on it last week! Great puzzle by the way! +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to indicate

> how many squares a [chess](/questions/tagged/chess) knight can jump to; it's forbidden to jump to the black squares.

There are some exceptions to this rule,

> indicated with freehand circles in the picture below:
>  [image]
>
>  Their number is one too much in all cases, and they form a nice pattern: from there, a knight could jump to the central square. That means that if the central square would be black instead of a 7, all numbers would be correct.

Answer (score 3):

The incorrect square is:

> the middle 7. It should be black.